# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined in angular when filtering products

Tags: javascript, angular, database, firebase

I am having this problem  in component Type `{ data: Product[]; id: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]`.
  Type `{ data: Product[]; id: string; }` is missing the following properties from type `'Product': title, price, category, imageUrl`. When i am trying to assign the values returned from database to

```
this.filterdProduct =  this.Product = products;
```

In Constructor...

Here is my code: Interface

```
export interface Product{
   title:string;
   price:number;
   category:string;
   imageUrl:string;
}
```

```
    Service.Ts:

import { Product } from './../../new-products';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireDatabase  } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {


  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase){}
  create(product){
   return this.db.list('/products').push(product);

  }
  getAll() {
    return this.db.list<Product[]>('/products').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(a => 
        a.map(
      ac => {

          const data= ac.payload.val();
          const id = ac.key;
          // console.log(data);
          // console.log(id)
          return {data,id} 

        } )
    )
    );

  }
```

```
    Component.ts:

import { Product } from './../../new-products';

import { ProductService } from './../Services/product.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.css']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {
  Product:Product []= [];
  filterdProduct:any = [];
  subscription: Subscription;



constructor(private pd:ProductService){
   this.subscription =  this.pd.getAll().subscribe(products => {
     this.filterdProduct =  this.Product = products;
    })
}
filter(query:string){ 
this.filterdProduct = (query) ? 
this.Product.filter(p => p.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) : this.Product;
console.log(query)
}

ngOnInit(){

}

ngOnDestroy(){
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

}
```

Comment: this.product in constructor showing the error...

Comment: Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @sandeepkumarBrungi try to print this.Product in console.

Comment: Please post the full error so that we can understand it better

Comment: @Yeheshuah: Thanks for your suggestion. As i am new to this world..:)

Answer (score 0):

getAll service function return a object, it's not a Product[], but { Product[], id}

```
ac => {

          const data= ac.payload.val();
          const id = ac.key;
          // console.log(data);
          // console.log(id)
          return {data,id} <-- Here

        } )
```

It has to return a Product[].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `getAll` function. You are returning an object of type `{data, id}`. You should return `data` as your error signifies that you are expected to return an `array` of `Product`.

Comment: Error in console: Cannot read property  'toLowerCase' of undefined.

Comment: in component this.product indicate error as::    Type { data: Product[]; id: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]. Type { data: Product[]; id: string; } is missing the following properties from type 'Product': title, price, category, imageUrl

Answer (score 0):

`Product:Product []= [];`
in AdminProductsComponent field should be renamed to `product` and not `Product` as it clashes with interface name so it should be like this -
`product: Array<Product> = [];`

What is preventing you from using following code?

```
const data = ac.payload.val();
data.id = ac.key;
return data;
```